# How to formate variable returned as /Date(1465196400000)/ into a real date

Tags: php, wordpress

I am pulling from an API, the variables StartDate and EndDate return as /Date(1465196400000)/, can you advise the best approach to format this as a real date such as mm/dd/yy?

The /Date is throwing me off.

Comment: Extract the numeric part using a regexp or similar; divide by 1000; then treat it as a unix timestamp and pass it to the [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function or a [DateTime object](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) and use the format() method to return a human-formatted date string

Comment: Can you send me to a page that shows an example? Sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can convert it to a date using [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php):

```
$data = '/Date(1465196400000)/';

if (preg_match('#/Date\((\d+)\)/#', $data, $result)) {
    $date = date('d-m-Y', $result[1] / 1000);
    echo $date; // 06-06-2016
};
```